# Spring & Hibernate - to get persisteed object state changed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

In my webapp, Spring transaction and Hibernate session API are used.
Please see my service and DAO classes and usage below;

**BizCustomerService**

```
@Service
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class BizCustomerService {

    @Autowired
    CustomerService customerService;

    public void createCustomer(Customer cus) {
        //some business logic codes here

        customerService.createCustomer(cus);

        //***the problem is here, changing the state of 'cus' object
        //it is necessary code according to business logic
        if (<some-check-meet>)
            cus.setWebAccount(new WebAccount("something", "something"));
    }
}
```

**CustomerService**

```
@Service
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class CustomerService {

    @Autowired
    CustomerDAO customerDao;

    public Long createCustomer(Customer cus) {
        //some code goes here
        customerDao.save();
    }
}
```

**CustomerDAO**

```
@Repository
public class CustomerDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    public Long save(Customer customer) {
        //* the old code
        //return (Long) getSession().save(customer);

        //[START] new code to change
        Long id = (Long) getSession().save(customer);

        //1. here using 'customer' object need to do other DB insert/update table functions
        //2. if those operation are failed or success, as usual, they are under a transaction boundary
       //3. lets say example private method
       doSomeInsertUpdate(customer);
       //[END] new code to change

        return id;
    }

    //do other insert/update operations 
    private void doSomeInsertUpdate(customer) {

         //when check webAccount, it is NULL
         if (customer.getWebAccount() != null) {
              //to do something
         }

    }
}
```

**Customer**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
public class Customer {
     //other relationships and fields

     @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "customer")
     @Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
     public WebAccount getWebAccount() {
          return this.webAccount;
     }
}
```

In the above code, customer is created in `BizCustomerService` then may change the state of related `WebAccount` after persisted through DAO. And when the transaction is committed, a new Customer and related `WebAccount` object are persisted to DB. This is normal I know.

The problem is; in `CustomerDAO#save() >> doSomeInsertUpdate()` method, 'webAccount' is NULL and the value is not set yet at that time.

**EDIT** : Left to mention that, it is restricted and don't want to change the code at `BizCustomerService` and `CustomerService` because there can be many invocations to DAO methods it can impact alot. So want to change only at DAO level.

**So my question is how can I access WebAccount object in doSomeInsertUpdate() method? Any Hibernate usage needed?**

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Didn't you already access WebAccount object in your doSomeInsertUpdate method ? as seen in your code `if (customer.getWebAccount() != null)` ? Or do i miss something ?

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you're expecting, but I think there is no magic here. If you want a WebAccount to be `!= null`, you'll have to explicitly make one and save it to the DB.

```
WebAccount wb = new WebAccount();
getSession().save(wb);
customer.setWebAccount(wb);
```